# iPhone: value of selectedIndex for tab should be consistent, but isn't

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

This should be so simple... but something screwy is happening.

My setup looks like this:

```
MainViewController
   Tab Bar Controller
      4 tabs, each of which loads WebViewController
```

My AppDelegate contains an ivar, tabBarController, which is connected to the tab bar controller (this was all set up in Interface Builder).  The leftmost tab is marked "selected" in IB.

Within the viewWillAppear method in WebViewController, I need to know which tab was just selected so I can load the correct URL.  I do this by switching on appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex.

When the app first runs and the leftmost tab is selected, selectedIndex is a large garbage value.  After that, I get values from 0 to 3, which is as it should be, but they are in random order.  Not only that, but each tab I touch reports a different value each time.

This app is *extremely* simple right now and I can't imagine what I could have done to make things go this wrong.

Has anyone seen (and hopefully solved) this behavior?

Update:  we have a request for code.  There's not much to see.

The tab bar controller gets loaded in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[self.mainViewController view];  //force nib to load
[self.window addSubview:self.mainViewController.tabBarController.view]
```

There is currently no code whatsoever in MainViewController.m other than the synthesize and release for tabBarController.

From WebVewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)_animation {
    [super viewWillAppear:_animation];

    NSURL *url;
    switch([S_UIDelegate mainViewController].tabBarController.selectedIndex) {
        case 0: url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cnn.com"];
            break;
        case 1: url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
            break;
        case 2: url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com"];
            break;
        case 3: url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
            break;
        default: url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.msnbc.com"];
    }

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

This is where I'm seeing the random values. BTW, S_UIDelegate is just a macro that returns a pointer to the app delegate.  I'm using someone else's app template and he's a huge fan of #define to save on typing.

Comment: Have you tried to assign a value to selectedIndex to see what happens.

Comment: Is your tabController connected to the appDelegate or to the mainViewcontroller ?

Comment: The tab bar controller is connected to the ivar tabBarController within MainViewController.  I haven't tried assigning a value;  I guess I could do that in viewWillAppear in MainViewController and see if it has any effect.  I shouldn't need to do that, though, should I?

Comment: setting selectedIndex to 0 in MainViewController's viewWillAppear does not fix it (and yes, I'm aware that you wouldn't want to set it back to the first tab every time, but it was an easy place to try).

Comment: I've just tried in my app. it appears that the selectedIndex I get in viewwillAppear is the index of the previously selected tab. (except the first time...)

Comment: `-viewWillAppear:` isn't called by `UITabBarController`, so there must be custom code in your app that's making the call. Similarly, you might want to check to see whether your `MainViewController`'s `-viewWillAppear:` method is getting called.

Answer (score 6):

A co-worker just provided the answer.  selectedIndex isn't set up yet in viewWillAppear;  when I switched to using viewDidAppear instead, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to move your switch case into a tabBarController delegate :
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController: